# ListView ItemDataBound Issue

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a ListView displaying Products. I'm trying to add a Category label before each list of products, where each category may have several products. I'm trying to achieve this without nesting ListViews. Right now the issue is that it is repeating the category name over every product name. This is not what I want. I only want it to list the category name over products when the category name changes. Both Product and Category are being returned from the same DB table.

**Category 1**

Product 1

Product 2

**Category 2**

Product 3

Product 4

```
<asp:ListView ID="classesList" ItemPlaceholderID="classesPlaceHolder"
    OnItemDataBound="ClassesList_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="classesPanel" CssClass="classesPanel" runat="server">                       
             <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="classesPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </asp:Panel>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <strong><asp:Label ID="categoryNameLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong>
            <a href='#'><%# Eval("product_name") %></a><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

protected void ClassesList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        Label categoryNameLabel = e.Item.FindControl("categoryNameLabel") as Label;

        if (!categoryNameLabel.Text.Contains(row["cat_name"].ToString())) 
        {
            categoryNameLabel.Text = row["cat_name"].ToString() + "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this in a loop would be trivial. But since the ItemDataBound event fires for every data item coming back, I'm trying to find a simple way of doing this.

**UPDATE**

I moved the data binding out of the Page Load method to a method called GetClasses(). This new method is called from the first page load. I gave up on the ItemDataBound method as I wanted to implement a loop and toggle the visibility of the categoryLabel. Unfortunately, no category is appearing now so maybe I'm missing something?

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <strong><asp:Label ID="categoryNameLabel" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a href='#'><%# Eval("product_name") %></a><br />
    </ItemTemplate>

    public void GetClasses()
    {
        DataSet ds = CatalogDALC.GetClassesByCategory(categoryID, DateTime.Now);
        classesList.DataSource = ds;
        classesList.DataBind();

        // Set main category header for classes - loop here and set category name headers
        int count = 0;
        foreach (ListViewDataItem item in classesList.Items)
        {
            Label categoryNameLabel = item.FindControl("categoryNameLabel") as Label;

            if (count == 0) // Set the first category name header regardless
            {
                categoryNameLabel.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["cat_name"].ToString() + "<br />";
                categoryNameLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[count-1]["cat_name"].ToString() != ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["cat_name"].ToString())
                {
                    categoryNameLabel.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["cat_name"].ToString() + "<br />";
                    categoryNameLabel.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    categoryNameLabel.Visible = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            count++;
       }
 }
```

Comment: add global `currentCategory` and hide (`visible="false"`) the label when it is the same. Update when changed.

Comment: Have you looked into the ListView `GroupTemplate`? [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.grouptemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Alex, I tried toggling the visibility but couldn't get it to work. If you could provide a code snippet that would be cool.

Comment: zgood, I hadn't thought of the GroupTemplate outside if tiling layouts but will take a look.

Comment: Alex, I tried your suggestion and updated the question. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My updated solution in the question was the right approach - the only bug was the continue statement - it was bypassing the counter. This is the working version for anyone in a similar situation:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <strong><asp:Label ID="categoryNameLabel" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a href='#'><%# Eval("product_name") %></a><br />
    </ItemTemplate>

    public void GetClasses()
    {
        DataSet ds = CatalogDALC.GetClassesByCategory(categoryID, DateTime.Now);
        classesList.DataSource = ds;
        classesList.DataBind();

        // Set main category header for classes - loop here and set category name headers
        int count = 0;
        foreach (ListViewDataItem item in classesList.Items)
        {
            Label categoryNameLabel = item.FindControl("categoryNameLabel") as Label;

            if (count == 0) // Set the first category name header regardless
            {
                categoryNameLabel.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["cat_name"].ToString() + "<br />";
                categoryNameLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[count-1]["cat_name"].ToString() != ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["cat_name"].ToString())
                {
                    categoryNameLabel.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[count]["cat_name"].ToString() + "<br />";
                    categoryNameLabel.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            count++;
       }
 }
```